# maven plugin development: get state of integration tests

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

I'm developing a maven plugin to instantiate and power on a vmware vapp template during pre-integration-test phase, determine the IPs for the integration-test and after post-integration-test phase to undeploy and delete the vapp. But: I only want to delete the vapp when all integrationtests have been successful.

Is there any way to get the state of the surefire or failsafe plugin in the context of my plugin?

Thanks for any hints.

Edit 1:

Using the code now as in the VerifyMojo of the failsafe plugin to later check the failsafeResult. But I'm still searching a better way. Isn't there any build context available like the project API?

```
 public void verify() throws IOException, XmlPullParserException {
    FileInputStream fos = new FileInputStream(summaryFile);
    BufferedInputStream bos = new BufferedInputStream(fos);
    String encoding;
    if (StringUtils.isEmpty(this.encoding)) {
        getLog().warn(
                "File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding "
                        + ReaderFactory.FILE_ENCODING
                        + ", i.e. build is platform dependent!");
        encoding = ReaderFactory.FILE_ENCODING;
    } else {
        encoding = this.encoding;
    }
    Reader w = new InputStreamReader(bos, encoding);
    FailsafeSummaryXpp3Reader reader = new FailsafeSummaryXpp3Reader();
    final FailsafeSummary summary = reader.read(w);
    failsafeResult = summary.getResult();
    w.close();
    bos.close();
    fos.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you do it as you've described?

1. Create/Invoke a goal before the integration tests in order to start your VM by tying the goal to the `pre-integration-test`.
2. Create/Invoke a goal after the integration tests have run in order to stop your VM by tying the goal to the `post-integration-test`.

This is all as per your description in the question.

If your integration tests fail, step 2) will not get executed and, therefore, the vapp will not get undeployed/deleted.

Comment: we're using the failsafe plugin for integration test phase and post-integration-test gets executed even with failed tests then, am i right?

And I want to safe system resources by even undeploy the vapp in suspend mode and only delete it with successful integration tests.

Comment: Hm... I wouldn't expect the integration tests would get executed, if the regular ones have failed.